# Jquery repeater with select2 not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, repeater

I am seaching from 2 days about this issue.

The first element is working perfectly. But after repeat the element, previous element's select2 fields destroyed automatically.

There is two rop divs in repeater. When first one selected by the ajax request I am appending the options to values section.

Here is the screenshot for reference.

[image]

Here is the code for repeater and select2 initialization.

```
<script>
        $(function () {

            $(".attribute_list").on('change', ".attribute", function (e) {
                var attr_name = $(this).attr('name');
                var attr_id = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{ route('products.getValue') }}",
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                    },
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: '{"attr_id": "' + attr_id + '", "attr_name" : "' + attr_name + '"}',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var attribute_value = data.attribute_value;
                        var field_name = 'select[name="product_attribute[' + data.field_name + '][attribute_values][]"]';

                        if (attribute_value) {
                            $(field_name).empty();
                            $.each(attribute_value, function (key, value) {
                                $(field_name).append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.value + '</option>');
                            });
                            // $(field_name).select2();

                        } else {
                            $(field_name).empty();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
    <script>
        // $("#attribute_button").click(function(){
        //     $('#attribute_values').select2({
        //                 placeholder: "select attribute value"
        //             });
        // });
        window.onload = function () {
            $('.attribute_values').select2({
                placeholder: "select attribute value",
                allowClear: true
            });
        }

        $('.repeater').repeater({

            initEmpty: false,
            show: function () {
                $(this).slideDown();
                $('.attribute_values').select2({
                    placeholder: "select attribute value"
                });
            },

            hide: function (deleteElement) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this element?')) {
                    $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
                }
            },

            ready: function (setIndexes) {
            },
        })
```